# comparisons vs arithmetic complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reference-request

I'm trying to find out which operation is fast, evaluating a comparison vs doing an arithmetic option on a single word (e.g subtract, add). Can anyone point me in the right direction with some blogs, books and other material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It principle it could depend on the processor. However, I imagine that comparison are done using the same circuitry as subtraction, so the complexity should be comparable. I'm assuming that by *comparison* you mean an instruction comparing two registers and setting some flags (or another register). A conditional jump might interfere with pipelining and so would be costlier.

Comment: +1 SPARC actually uses a subtraction instruction with the zero register as a destination for comparison. *In theory*, an equality check is modestly easier than less-than/greater-than and comparison to zero is slightly easier than that, which along with commonness is why some RISCs support them for branch instructions. ISAs with condition codes typically allow a version of subtraction to set those codes, so treating compare as flag-only subtraction is simpler. Providing special hardware would often add complexity without benefit.